# Resize and repositon div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, coding-style, resize

I'm trying to do a simple resize and reposition of a div element that shows a ajax loading image.  The content it loads can change size, so I want the div element to resize to be the size of the parent, which in this case is a table dimension with the id "thEngineCategories".

```
function resize_divProgress() {
    var control = document.getElementById('thEngineCategories');
    var div = document.getElementById('divProgress');

    div.style.left = control.offsetLeft + 'px';
    div.style.top = control.offsetTop + 'px';
    div.style.width = control.offsetWidth + 'px';
    div.style.height = control.offsetHeight + 'px';
}
```

The following is the javascript I have and it errors on

```
div.style.left = control.offsetLeft + 'px';
```

saying "div.style is undefined".  Whats wrong here?

The div in html is as follows:

```
<div class="overlay" id="divProgress">
```

The js function is called as follows:

```
<th id="thEngineCategories" onmouseover="resize_divProgress()" >
```

The CSS is:

```
.overlay
{
    border: black 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    -moz-opacity: 0.75;
    opacity: 0.75;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Is there a better way to handle what I'm trying to do?

Comment: What, if any, javascript library are you using?

Comment: I know another developer was loading jQuery in one of the master pages, but I'm not sure if its here to stay, so I want to keep this simple and library independent.

Comment: your code looks ok - are you sure that 'div' is not undefined?

Comment: In firebug, it appears to be defined fine.  If I hover over the div variable, it shows div#divProgress.overlay.  I forgot this is in a master/content page, so I'll change to using ClientID

Comment: Nvm, these aren't runat="server" controls.  No ClientID needed.

Comment: try console.log'ing div and div.style before your assignments.

Comment: Console.log(div) results in: <div id="divProgress" class="overlay">, then undefined
Console.log(div.style) results in: CSSStyleDeclaration length=0, then undefined

Comment: Those sound like reasonable values. Do you mean that it prints "undefined", or that it has the error? If it's the former, it sounds like the function is being called twice, and the second time the div can't be found.

Comment: It displays the <div id="divProgress" class="overlay"> on the first line.  On the next line it says undefined.

Comment: One thing to remember when positioning elements in this way: Table elements like th and td can be extremely unreliable in reporting their locations and dimensions, especially in IE, and especially if you have them set to center horizontally within a container. If at all possible, do not use tables for layout purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [created a basic test page](http://pastebin.com/f35593ddb) from the code you provided and couldn't reproduce the problem. This suggests there is something else going on in your page that is causing the behaviour you are seeing.

Could you take your page and pare it down to a minimal case that demonstrates the JavaScript error? You'll find performing this process often will reveal the cause of the error - you'll remove something and it will start working, indicating that something in that removed section of code is the source of the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

div.style.width is not valid property for accessing width of div.

use **div.offsetWidth** and **div.offsetHeight** for width and height respectively.