# HTML not displaying correctly in IE compatibilty mode

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, ie-compatibility-mode

I have a `div` on an HTML page that works fine in IE8, IE9, and other browsers, but when opening the page in compatability mode, it doesn't show correctly.

A small (37px wide) tab should appear on the left of the screen. When the user clicks on the tab it expands to 200px. In compatability mode all the user sees is the 37px tab with some of the content that is hidden.

I have added `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=5,7,8,9" />` to the top of the page, but it needs to work for any version of IE.

Below is the markup that is being used.

```
<div id="divChat" 
        style="height:125px; width:100px; top:200px; left:0px; position:fixed; overflow:hidden; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #666666; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #666666; box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #666666;">
    <div style="float:right;">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout:fixed;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:200px; background-color:#FFFFFF; text-align:center; vertical-align:top; padding-left:10px;">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="maintextdark" style=" text-align:left; font-size:21px; font-weight:normal; padding-top:10px;">
                                Have any questions?
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="maintextdark" style="font-size:14px; text-align:left; padding-top:6px;">
                                Ask one of our advisors.
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: left; padding-top: 10px;"  onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'">
                                <div id='LP_DIV_1351175355234' style='width:161px;height:34px;'/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td style="width:37px; height:125;">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'">
                                <img id="imgChatNow" src="images/chatnowout.png" alt="" width="37" height="125" border="0" onmouseout="this.src = setMouseOut(this.src);"
                                    onmouseover="this.src = setMouseOver(this.src);" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

This CSS is called by JavaScript:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .LivePersonHoverOff
    {
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
        filter: alpha(opacity=70);
        -moz-opacity: 0.7;
        -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
        opacity: 0.7;
        background-image: url(images/chatonlineout.png);
        }

</style>
```

This is the JavaScript that is used

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#LP_DIV_1351175355234").hover(
                                                function () {
                                                    $(this).addClass("LivePersonHoverOff");
                                                },
                                                function () {
                                                    $(this).removeClass("LivePersonHoverOff");
                                                }
                                                );
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var chatExpanded = false;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#imgChatNow").click(function () {
            if (chatExpanded == true) {
                $("#divChat").animate({ width: "37px" }, 500, "swing", function () {
                    chatExpanded = false;
                    $("#imgChatNow").attr("src", "images/chatnowout.png");
                    $('#imgChatNow').bind('mouseover', function () {
                        $('#imgChatNow').attr("src", "images/chatnowover.png");
                    });
                    $('#imgChatNow').bind('mouseout', function () {
                        $('#imgChatNow').attr("src", "images/chatnowout.png");
                    });
                });
            } else {
                $("#divChat").animate({ width: "247px" }, 500, "swing", function () {
                    chatExpanded = true;
                    $("#imgChatNow").attr("src", "images/chatnow2over.png");
                    $('#imgChatNow').bind('mouseover', function () {
                        $('#imgChatNow').attr("src", "images/chatnow2over.png");
                    });
                    $('#imgChatNow').bind('mouseout', function () {
                        $('#imgChatNow').attr("src", "images/chatnow2over.png");
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: compatibility mode renders as it was internet explorer 7. You probably trigger a javascript click event that is not supported as of IE7. But there is no click in your code, so I can't tell.

Comment: Can you put this up at jsfiddle?

Comment: Trying to add the javascript but cant see how to do it

Comment: @Neograph734 have posted the JavaScript

Comment: There are 2 tables in the div. In compatability mode it sets the width of the div to 37px but doesnt display the image and therefore the JavaScript doesnt run as it is looking for this image

Answer (score 2):

I would use javascript for this. Just write something. ( [Resize and repositon div using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650916/resize-and-repositon-div-using-javascript) )

(If you have png why do you use opacity. Opacity doesnt work in older Browser.)

Comment: The png is used to display different button images. What would you use instead of opacity?

Comment: Change the alpha channel from the png with any photomanipulation programm (set 70% transparenz).

Comment: I do have some JavaScript that expands and resizes the divs. That doesnt seem to be the issue, its how its being displayed when the screen first loads

Comment: Do I understand you right, you want an div that gain size on click.

Comment: Yes that is correct. It works fine except in compatability mode

Comment: Hmm strange but well *checking code* what about using onclick events cant see them. You can implement you functions in the onclickevent ( http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp ) 

edit: no idea if IE6 support them but well why you want IE6 support

Comment: I was going to post some screenshots but I dont have enough points and I am not allowed to post the link. The click function is in the JavaScript.

Comment: Ye you are right its hard to understand for me. And atm I dont have the time to rebuild it. Cant tell you yet sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I have sorted the problem. I changed the width of the div and set its left position to a minus figure.

In the JavaScript I changed the animate width to animate left and the number of pixels from 37 to -210 and 247px to 0px.

Thanks to all those who replied for your time